# PHP How to bisect an array with n levels

Tags: php

I am building an array with an unknown amount of levels:

```
$away_array [
   0 => [1,2,3],
   1 => [2,3,4],
   2 => [3,4,5]
   n..
 ]
```

What I would like to do is intersect the arrays.

PHP offers [array intersect.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

My question is: is it possible to use array intersect in the above example? Or is there an alternative option?

I am using PHP 7

EDIT - for clarity

As I have an unknown number of arrays that I wish to compare, I can not use array_interect in the usual manner:

```
result = array_intersect(array1,array2,array3);
```

Essentially I have an array of unknown number of arrays that I need to compare and return the common elements:

array = [
  0 => array1,
  1 => array2,
  2 => array3,
  3 => array4,
   n..
]

This would be entered:

```
$result = array_intersect(array1,array2,array3,array4,array...n)..
```

Obviously this is not possible...

So how can this be done recursively?

Comment: `to use array intersect` for what?

Comment: Look at `call_user_func_array()`

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123, that did the trick.